# How can I grep content from file1 matching file2 and put them in the order of file2

Tags: unix, grep

I have `file1.txt` with content:

```
rs002
rs113
rs209
rs227
rs151 
rs104
```

I have `file2.txt` with content:

```
rs113   113
rs002   002
rs227   227
rs209   209
rs104   104
rs151   151
```

I want to get the lines of `file2.txt` that match the records in `file1.txt`, for which I tried:

```
grep -Fwf file1.txt file2.txt
```

with output as follows:

```
rs113   113
rs002   002
rs227   227
rs209   209
rs104   104
rs151   151
```

This extracts all the matching lines, but it is in the order of occurrence in `file2.txt`. Is there any way to extract the matching records while maintaining the order from `file1.txt`? The desired output is as follows:

```
rs002   002
rs113   113
rs209   209
rs227   227
rs151   151
rs104   104
```

Comment: Have you tried reversing the arguments - `grep -Fwf file2.txt file1.txt`

Comment: @adarshr That won't work. What this grep command does is basically use the first file as the patterns you're looking for and the second file as the file in which you're looking for the patterns. As far as I know, you can't trick the sorting order just by using the grep command. Maybe awk or comm could help (not sure).

Comment: @adarshr tried reversing the files, but as user--randombee said, the first file is the one with particular pattern that we want the second file to follow while subsetting.

Answer (score 2):

One (amittedly not very elegant) solution is to loop over `file1.txt` and look for a match for each line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    grep -wF "$line" file2.txt
done < file1.txt
```

which gives the output

```
rs002   002
rs113   113
rs209   209
rs227   227
rs151   151
rs104   104
```

If you know that each line occurs only once at most, this can be accelerated a bit by telling grep to stop after the first match:

```
grep -m 1 -wF "$line" file2.txt
```

This is a GNU extension, as far as I can tell.

Notice that looping over a file to do some processing on another file in each loop usually is a [sign that there is a much more efficient way to do things](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), so this should probably only be used for files small enough where the effort of coming up with a better solution takes longer than processing them with this solution.

Comment: I will come back and  vote yes once I reach 15 reputation!

Comment: and there's the danger of posting a solution like this - that a newbie might actually think it's the right approach rather than just an interesting anecdote. reneesummer please read http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice as Benjamin suggested and then accept [@Thor's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36524323/1745001) which I'm sure Benjamin would agree is the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

This is too complicated for `grep`. If `file2.txt` is not huge, i.e. it fits into memory, you should probably be using `awk`:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR { f2[$1] = $2; next } $1 in f2 { print $1, f2[$1] }' file2.txt file1.txt
```

Output:

```
rs002 002
rs113 113
rs209 209
rs227 227
rs151 151
rs104 104
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a sed-command file from file2

```
 sed 's#^\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)#/\1/ s/$/\2/#' file2 > tmp.sed
 sed -f tmp.sed file1
```

These 2 lines can be combined avoiding the tmp file

```
sed -f <(sed 's#^\([^ ]*\)\(.*\)#/\1/ s/$/\2/#' file2) file1
```

Answer (score -1):

That should help (but will not optimal for big input):

```
$ for line in `cat file1.txt`; do grep $line file2.txt; done
```

Comment: Plese use `"$line"` for lines with more than 1 word.

Comment: Entirely the wrong approach with many issues. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice